# How does Java resolve generic type parameters that aren't in method declaration?

Tags: java, generics

While trying to solve a problem, I ended up writing a method with a type parameter that isn't mentioned in the arguments nor in the return type, namely a `<T> void authenticate(Credentials credentials)` method. The only dependency on `T` is in the method body (details ahead). So my question is: **how is that generic type resolved**? I couldn't find any other example code with that kind of generic type parameter.

So the body of that method is something like

```
public <T extends AuthResponse> void authenticate(Credentials credentials) {
    Call<T> call = getAuthCall(credentials);
    Response<T> response = call.execute();

    // doSomething is an AuthResponse method
    response.body().doSomething();
}
```

which calls a method with only a generic return type, which goes like this:

```
private Call<T extends AuthResponse> getAuthCall(Credentials credentials) {
    if (credentials instanceof CredentialsA)
        return (Call<T>) service.authenticate((CredentialsA) credentials);
    else if (credentials instanceof CredentialsB)
        return (Call<T>) service.authenticate((CredentialsB) credentials);
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

So the type parameters of the two methods seem to be related. But I couldn't understand how. Also the `(Call<T>)` cast doesn't seem like a nice solution to my problem — `service` is a Retrofit interface like this:

```
public interface AuthServiceInterface {
    @POST("auth/a") Call<AuthResponseA> authenticate(CredentialsA credentials);
    @POST("auth/b") Call<AuthResponseB> authenticate(CredentialsB credentials);
}
```

Comment: simple answer - java does not resove it, if you remove it and replace T with AuthResponse - nothing will change

Answer (score 3):

Compiler is able to infer type parameter `T` in return type `<T extends A>` based on the target variable. For example, compiler can understand that `T` is `String`, when you write

```
List<String> empty = Collections.emptyList();
```

In your example, the type is `<T extends AuthResponse>` on the both sides.

---

You should understand that type `T` in two methods might be different:

```
private Call<T extends AuthResponse> getAuthCall(Credentials credentials) {
    return (Call<T>) new BadAuthCall<BadResponse>(); // unchecked warning
}

public <T extends AuthResponse> void authenticate(Credentials credentials) {
    Call<T> call = getAuthCall(credentials);
    ...

// then somewhere in your code
Call<GoodResponse> response = service.authenticate(credentials);
// this code compiles, but will throw ClassCastException in runrime
```

First method gives unchecked warning, because return value is cast to `Call<T>` which can be anything on the caller side. Compiler tries to prevent us from exactly this situation, when we cast `Call<BadResponse>` to `Call<GoodResponse>`.

P.S. Don't worry about it, casts are most likely safe in your example.

---

And the last thing: since actual value of `T` is not known inside authenticate method, it is allowed to call only the methods of class `AuthResponse`. Strictly saying, `extends` keyword does not play a big role inside the method, it affects only the return value assignment to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of "inference" when you make a call to a generic method and don't provide an explicit type witness, is to find out whether there exists at least one type that can be chosen for `T` that will make the call compile. There may be more than one choice for `T` that would work, and in that case *it doesn't need to care which one* is chosen -- the compiler doesn't need to choose a type argument because it is not compiled into the bytecode anyway -- all it needs is to be satisfied that there is at least one valid choice, and then its job is done.

When the type parameter is not used in any parameter or return types, then, by definition, the choice of type for `T` won't affect whether the call compiles or not. Which means **the compiler can completely ignore the type parameter**, because it is irrelevant to the type-checking of the call.

Or, put another way, the compiler can arbitrarily choose any type within the bounds for `T`, e.g. it can choose `AuthResponse`, or `YourSubclassOfAuthResponse`, or `MadeUpSubclassOfAuthResponseThatDoesntExistInYourCode`. Doesn't matter. The choice doesn't affect whether the call compiles or not.

This absurdity points out that **a type parameter of a generic method that does not appear in the parameter or result types is completely meaningless and serves no possible purpose**.

Why does your method need to be generic? If your generic method compiles, then that means I can take it, and replace all occurrences of `T` with `AuthResponse` (or even with a newly-defined `UselessSubclassOfAuthResponse` that I add in your code), and it will also compile and be a perfectly-valid non-generic version of your method. Consider that for a moment. If I do that, then the first line will read `Call<UselessSubclassOfAuthResponse> call = getAuthCall(credentials);`. Does your `getAuthCall()` method return a `Call<UselessSubclassOfAuthResponse>` (or `Call<WhateverTheCallerWantsWithoutKnowingWhatItIs>`)? Probably not. If the type arguments of `Call` and `Response` can be arbitrarily altered without affecting the validity of the code, then either 1) They are unused and not necessary, or 2) Your code is fundamentally type-unsafe somewhere.